# how to write a cmake file that can run test depend on same level lib 

Tags: dependencies, cmake

Suppose that my project dirs like this:

```
src
|
|---lib1
|    |
|    |--lib1.cpp
|    |--lib1.hpp
|    |--lib1test.cpp
|
|---lib2
|    |
|    |--lib2.cpp
|    |--lib2.hpp
|    |--lib2test.cpp
|
|main.cpp
```

Now the lib1 has developed,and lib2 is on developing. Lib2 uses some features in lib1.I need do some test for lib2, this means when build lib2 tests under lib2, it should build lib1 first. How can I write three CMakeLists.txt files that lib2 test build depend on same level dir lib1?

Comment: я думаю гладиолус. Can't I answer the question using other language than English? :D

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/is-english-required-on-stack-overflow

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention are your libs `static` or `dynamic`. I'll assume they are both static (but it really doesn't matter). You should simply do something like this:

//core CMakeLists.txt

```
#...
add_subdirectory(lib1)
add_subdirectory(lib2)
```

//lib1 CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(lib1 lib1.cpp)
target_link_libraries(lib1 ${lib1_deps})
```

//lib2 CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(lib2 lib2.cpp)
add_dependencies(lib2 lib2.cpp) #actually don't need this line
target_link_libraries(lib2 lib1 ${lib2_deps})

add_executable(lib2test lib2test.cpp)
target_link_libraries(lib2test lib2)
```

Comment: Ok, just use static lib. But it is doesn't metter, this three files can not work, because the lib2 dosen't known lib1. When I entry lib2, the cmake can not find liblib1.a. Do you test your solution before answer?

Comment: If you use root `CMakeLists.txt` and create lib1 with `add_library` then cmake definetly should know where `lib1` is placed. When writing `target_link_libraries` how exactly are you specifying lib1 - by target name of by `liblib1.a`? You should use target name. Yeah, in our project we have similiar source code structure and this solution is tested. Can you show your `CMakeLists.txt` (concerning this libs) and actual error you received from `cmake`?

Comment: I know what you mean. But, if I don't want to compile the root target, how can I do with my question? If I have 100 lib(s) and i just want test lib2 with lib1, I won't compile in the top and 'make test', it'll be so long time, right? So, I must go into lib2 subdir and 'make test'. But your answer dosen't work. Last Sunday, I just thought about custom_command. Do you have some experience?